# ¿Cómo se escribe la interjección para denotar duda, interés o leve sorpresa? ¿Uhms?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, interjecciones, onomatopeyas

Acabo de ver el [comentario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18041/is-there-a-connection-between-embarazada-and-the-english-word-embarrassment#comment30955_20373) donde quien lo escribe muestra su escepticismo:

> Um, do you have any sources for any of your assertions? (...)

Está usando la interjección *um*, que se define en inglés como:

> [**Um**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/um?s=t)
>   1. used as an expression of doubt, hesitation, deliberation, interest, etc.

Y se me ha ocurrido pensar en cómo la diríamos en castellano. Yo siempre había escrito *Uhms* y realmente no sé por qué, pues el DRAE no la recoge ni por asomo. Lo que sí encuentro es:

> [**hum**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KnEraiH)
>   1. interj. desus. [uf](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b0zBgLN).

Y este *uf* es:

> [**uf**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b0zBgLN)
>   Voz onomat.
>   1. interj. U. para denotar cansancio, fastidio o sofocación.
>   2. interj. Indica repugnancia.

Por lo que no me parece que sea el mismo.

Fundéu dijo en [hum, ¡hum!](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/hum-hum-864/) que:

> La forma correcta en español es hum y puede escribirse entre signos de exclamación: ¡hum!

Pero sigo pensando que no es la palabra que busco.

¿Qué interjección u onomatopeya utilizamos para designar duda, leve sorpresa o interés?

Comment: Sé a lo que te refieres, pero francamente nunca he escuchado algo que suene a "uhms". Sin la 's' final sería un simple 'hum'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues... las respuestas que se han aportado hasta ahora no me convencen del todo.

En la primera frase de la pregunta, fedorqui (¿cómo se dice *original poster*?) explicó el uso de "um" mejor que la definición citada: expresa *escepticismo.*  Ejemplo:

> An alternative would be to engage in some serious SEO to get our skeptic pages ranked above Wikipedia in Google. **Um,** good luck with that. If you can crack that nut, go make a billion dollars and create a skeptical endowment fund.

"Um," tal y como se utiliza comunmente en Stack Exchange, expresa sucintamente la idea:

> Con todo respecto, creo que te equivocas.

Pero puede ser un poco sarcástico, como explica el [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=um):

> More recently used to unintentionally irritate people who prefer straight forward answers. Literally, "something is urgently wrong but instead of me just immediately telling you, you must figure it out yourself in the amount of time it takes me to make this sarcastic and unhelpful remark."
>
> Can be typed as well.
>
> Example, this used to be proper protocol in an urgent situation--
>
> Bob: "Joe, watch out for that large pothole you seem to be unknowingly driving into."
>
> Joe: (avoiding pothole) “Thank you for your timely and straight-forward warning. I appreciate you using the first sentence after you were alerted to this danger to tell me about this pothole, instead of uttering a one-worded, useless phrase.”
>
> Modern protocol, same situation--
>
> Bob: (sarcastically) "Um..."
>
> Joe: “What?..... What?” (car drives into pothole)
>
> Bob: “Wow, good job.”

Ahora bien, ¿cómo se puede expresar esta idea, igual de sucintamente, en español?

**1. Pues...**

Creo que la [definición del DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UawHjxX) que me apoya aquí es

> 5 - A principio de cláusula para apoyarla o encarecer lo dicho en ella. *Pues como iba diciendo. ¡Pues no faltaba más!*

O sea, empezar una frase de diálogo con "pues" da a entender que lo que viene a continuación es un tanto obvio.

Ejemplos:

> a) Pues... quizás obtendremos mejor resultado enchufando el aparato.
>
> b) Pues... estaría más dispuesto a aceptar tu afirmación si ofrecieras algún tipo de documentación.

**2. Este...** *(funciona bien en México pero no sé por los demás países)*

> interj. coloq. esto. *Este.… Quería contarles algo grave.* U. especialmente en Am.

"Este..." se usa para expresar duda, y ganarse un poco más tiempo.  Ejemplos:

> a) Este... ¿será mejor enchufarlo?
>
> b) Este... ¿tienes alguna fuente de documentación?

**Variante: Esto...** (o quizás "este" es variante de "esto")

> *interj. coloq.* Expresa duda o vacilación respecto de lo que se va a decir. *Esto… Quería pedirles un favor.*  ([DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GoDU5PI))

Los puntos suspensivos ayudan a dar el efecto deseado.  Desafortunadamente, no he encontrado documentación del escepticismo que esta palabrita logra expresar en ciertos contextos.

Comment: OP = original poster yo lo traduciría como _autor de la pregunta_. Escepticismo, esa es la clave. Pues creo que me convences, especialmente con el uso de _Este..._, que de hecho yo uso bastante con _Esto..._.

Comment: @fedorqui - Aquí en Spanish SE, ¿los usuarios me van a entender si digo, por ejemplo, *En la primera frase de la pregunta, el OP explicó etc.*?

Comment: They may, but I don't think it is safe to use it. All in all, most of our readers are not even registered users, so we cannot assume they know all this jargon that will make it more difficult to understand the full text. I would go for a mere impersonal _En la primera frase de la pregunta, **se explica** que..._

Comment: Side note: in your [last revision](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/revisions/20400/4) you say _el variante_. Note _variante_ is feminine, so we say _la variante_.

Comment: yo diría a voz de pronto que la única diferencia entre usar "este..." y "esto..." es el lugar. Si oigo a alguien decir "este..." automáticamente supongo que es de origen sudaméricano, mientras que el "esto..." lo oigo mas por España.

Comment: @Brian - Gracias.  "Este..." se dice en México también; ¿quizás se podría decir que se puede suponer que es de origen latinoamericano?

Comment: @aparente001 Perdón si, a eso me refería. :)

Answer (score 7):

Aunque no salga en la versión 'online' del diccionario, la RAE comentó en Twitter:

> [Mmmm](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/326616616387346432?lang=en)
>   *El uso de la onomatopeya «mmm» para expresar duda o satisfacción es correcto: Mmm..., no lo sé. ¡Mmmmm, qué rico!*

y luego:

> La interj. «**hmm**» es válida. Se documenta ya en 1891: «—Hmmm
>   —contestó el juez» (E. Pardo Bazán). Más frec., «hum».

Alternativas:

- [ajá (o ajajá)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1Ls5iVw)  *interj. coloq. U. para denotar satisfacción, aprobación o sorpresa.*
- [ujú](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b1Q3KFv)  *interj. Nic. U. para expresar acuerdo y aprobación de lo que afirma el interlocutor.*

Comment: Mmmm creo que me convence

Comment: AlexBcn, en Colombia, he escuchado que _ajá_ es igual a "si, claro, afirmativo, etc".

Answer (score 2):

Yo siempre he escrito la interjección de sorpresa o duda como "ah" o "ahm" (aunque esta última no la recoge la RAE):

> **[ah](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1GNbcOe)**
>
> 1. interj. U. para denotar pena, admiración, sorpresa o sentimientos similares.

Ejemplos:

> *—Anoche no estabas tú en el baile, ¿verdad? No te vi.
>
>   —¿Pero no te estoy diciendo que acabo de venir?
>
>   —¿Venir de dónde?
>
>   —De San Sebastián.
>
>   —Ah, qué suerte, tú. Estaría estupendo.*
>
> Carmen Martín Gaite, "Entre visillos", 1958 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *—¿Marta? Sí, Natalia. ¿Me llamó alguien?... Ah, y... ¿qué dijo? Ah, bueno. No, yo lo veo mañana... ¿A mí? Superbién. Sí, mucho... Bueno, gracias pues. Chaíto —clic.*
>
> Santiago Gamboa, "Páginas de vuelta", 1998 (Colombia).
>
> ---
>
> *—Yo no sé, Alvarez, lo que pasa en mi corazón. A las veces sólo quiero acordarme de Ramiro, y me siento como hechizada. ¡Ah, y qué celos me asaltan!*
>
> Enrique Larreta, "La gloria de don Ramiro. Una vida en tiempos de Felipe Segundo.", 1908 (Argentina).

Como puedes comprobar por los ejemplos, es una interjección bastante universal (tanto en propósito como en zonas de influencia). El primer ejemplo denota sorpresa y admiración por el sitio visitado; el segundo ejemplo denota leve sorpresa (las dos veces); el tercer ejemplo denota pena.

Para expresar el escepticismo tal vez no sea la mejor opción, ahora que lo veo, así que te propongo otra alternativa:

> **Ya**, ¿y en qué te basas para afirmar tal cosa?

Este uso de "ya" se ve reflejado [en el DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c8KthXc) como:

> 8. adv. U. para conceder o apoyar lo que nos dicen. *Ya se ve. Ya entiendo.*

Lo que pasa es que en este tipo de oraciones (que equivalen a "ya entiendo, ¿y en qué te basas...?", solo que "entiendo" está omitido) el adverbio se usa en modo irónico, mostrando por tanto el escepticismo del que habla. En el habla suele ir precedido de un "mmm" o de "hmm", por lo que me remito a la respuesta de AlexBcn.

Comment: Gracias por la tan detallada respuesta. Me descubre mucho, pues _ah_ no lo había relacionado nunca con un contexto de sorpresa y me sigue costando verlo como traducción al texto de mi pregunta: _Ah, ¿tienes fuentes...?_ Pero tampoco me sonaba _uf_ como lo define el DRAE, así que será cuestión de asimilarlo...

Comment: @fedorqui te he ampliado un poco la respuesta, dado que parece que me había ido un poco por los cerros de Úbeda.